# Flutter mqtt - Unicode(Korean) doesn't work

Tags: flutter, unicode, mqtt

I am using `mqtt_client: ^9.6.8` in my flutter project.

1. I want to subscribe to Korean topics, like topic: "test/안녕"
2. I want to get messages in Korean, like message: "안녕하세요"

currently if I try to subscribe to a korean topic, the client disconnects and the process just kills itself.

The log was a little bit different before, but this is the current log after I subscribe to a korean topic.

```
I/flutter (18972): 1-2022-08-09 15:38:40.135206 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
I/flutter (18972): 1-2022-08-09 15:38:40.135985 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::stop - stopping keep alive
I/flutter (18972): EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection
I/flutter (18972): EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected callback is unsolicited or none, this is incorrect - exiting
D/HostConnection(18972): createUnique: call
F/libc    (18972): FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0xb400006dd36425a0)
D/HostConnection(18972): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb400006de3607310, tid 19012
F/libc    (18972): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 19013 (1.raster), pid 18972
```

if I send a korean message, then it comes like `HÅU±` which is not what I want.

I tried to decode with utf8 but I can't seem to do it correctly.

Any helps on this? thanks for every suggestion!!

--edit--

this is the part where I print the received mqtt message

```dart
client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
      final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      final pt =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);

      context.read<SubTopic>().newTopic(c[0].topic);
      context.read<SubMessage>().newMessage(pt);

      print('Notification: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <$pt>');
    });
```

this is where I subscribe to the topic

```dart
try {
    await client.connect();
  } on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
    print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    print('EXAMPLE::socket exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
  }

  if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
    print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected');
    for (String topic in _subTopicList) {
      print(topic);
      client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);
    }
  } else {
    print(
        'EXAMPLE::ERROR Mosquitto client connection failed - disconnecting, status is ${client.connectionStatus}');
    client.disconnect();
    // exit(-1);
  }
```

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'안녕' .encode('utf-16-le').decode('cp1252')` returns `'HÅU±'`.

Comment: What broker are you using? (if it's one you control then please add broker logs to your question). Also are you sure that it's the call to `client.subscribe` that is causing the disconnect? (a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it simpler to identify possible causes).

Comment: @JosefZ any tips on how i can solve it?

Comment: @Brits yes because when the topic is all english, everything works well; when I change it to Korean then it is disconnected. I can't decode the message to utf8.